# The elements in my <li></li> aren't being displayed on the browser nor in the elements section in the inspect. Only my <ol> tags show

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging, jsx

The elements in my

aren't being displayed on the browser nor in the elements section in the inspect. Only my  tags show up in the browser when I inspect the page. Also, the value of total doesn't show up either. However, the items in the birdInCart do exist because when I console.log I can see the items in the array. Why isn't the result from my map function being rendered to the page?

Here is my code:

Cart.js file:

```
export default function Cart({ birdInCart, total }) {
    return (
        <div className="cart">
            <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
            <ol>
                {birdInCart?.map((bird)=> ( 
                    <li key={bird.id}>
                        <p>{bird.name}: {bird.amount}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ol>
            <h4>Cart Total: ${total}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.Js file:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import BirdCard from "./components/BirdCard";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";

function App() {
  const [birdInCart, setBirdInCart] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const addToCart = (bird) => {
    const birdCartItem = {
        id: Math.random(),
        name: bird.name,
        price: bird.amount,
        image: bird.image,
    };
    //setBirdInCart(birdInCart.push(birdCartItem)) - this is not going to work because the push method returns the new length of an array & not the update array. Instead I have to use the spread operator

    setBirdInCart([...birdInCart, birdCartItem]);
    setTotal(total + birdCartItem.amount);
    console.log("it works")
    console.log(birdInCart)
  }


  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Noni's Bird Sanctuary</h1>
      </header>
      <BirdCard addToCart={addToCart}/>
      <Cart addToCart={addToCart}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I tried adding a return and nothing changed. I also console.log the array to check if it is empty. Array is not empty.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `BirdCard` component?

Comment: You never pass `birdInCart` to the `Cart` component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have applied the ternary operator wrong. If you are trying to iterate over `birdInCart` array trying doing as following:

```
 {birdInCart?({birdInCart.map((bird)=> ( 
 <li key={bird.id}>
 <p>{bird.name}: {bird.amount}</p> </li> ))}):
 <p>there is nothing to show</p>}
```

also by the given code add this to cart components props

```
<Cart addToCart={addToCart} birdInCart={birdInCart} total=total/>
```

and use these as props accordingly.

Comment: Three was no ternary operator in the original code and there isn't one in your code. In the question optional changing is used.  Your code on the other hand throws syntax error

Comment: sorry i didn't review it carfully
 this is what i intended to say.


{birdInCart?({birdInCart.map((bird)=> ( 
                <li key={bird.id}>
                    <p>{bird.name}: {bird.amount}</p>
                </li>
))}):<p>there is nothing to show</p>}


is this what you meant